# Categorical data counting

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I would like to count the values in the pandas input table. The example output after the computation is shown in table output. I have used the code:

```
df2 = table.groupby(['FC_LABEL','MSW_LABEL','CHH_LABEL','RM_LABEL','ASSET_LABEL']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

but I got the output as in the table Groupby.

[image: Input]

Table: Input

[!output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd290.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd290.png)

Table: output

[image: Groupby]

Table: Groupby

Answer (score 2):

Use melt and crosstab as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
Table = pd.DataFrame({"FC_LABEL":["Low", "Low", "High", "Low"],
                      "MSW_LABEL":["High", "Low", "High", "Middle"]})
    
pd.crosstab(Table.melt()['variable'], Table.melt()['value'])
```

Comment: I think for performance reason dont call twice same code `melt` here. So better is use `df1 = df.melt()
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['variable'], df1['value'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(var_name='type', value_name='val')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['type'], df1['val'])
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.melt()
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['variable'], df1['value'])
```

Or [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df2 = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```